# aws presigned upload URL return json?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

Is there a way to make a presigned aws upload URL return a json response if there is a error rather then a xml response.

Currently it returns something like the following if the url is expired.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>Request has expired</Message>
    <X-Amz-Expires>900</X-Amz-Expires>
    <Expires>2020-02-06T20:13:39Z</Expires>
    <ServerTime>2020-02-06T20:26:33Z</ServerTime>
    <RequestId>2A23445454569</RequestId>
    <HostId>oi3j4o5ij346?3464556756567/5675685745yfghr5y4/456345345=</HostId>
</Error>
```

Would be nice if this was a json response instead.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way. It is not specific to pre-signed-url endpoints but S3 doesn't return json but xml.

According to Error Responses [documentation of s3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/ErrorResponses.html#RESTErrorResponses);

---

## REST Error Responses

When an error occurs, the header information contains the following:

- Content-Type: application/xml
- An appropriate 3xx, 4xx, or 5xx HTTP status code

---

Also you may check list of available methods from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_Operations_Amazon_Simple_Storage_Service.html), as it can be seen they are all XML.